# Toggle an accordion in Pug with SCSS

Tags: css, sass, pug

I am working on a menu with pug js that requires a toggle function. I know how to do this with a pseudo-class in basic CSS, but I can't use that in this project.

Clicking on `span` does allow the accordion to open, however, the image does not change to the `.open` position.

### accordion.pug

```
label(class='xs-w4 add-title', for='discount2') 
  span(class='accordion')(data-toggle='open') Click to open
```

### accordion.css

```
.accordion {
  background-image: url(../images/arrow-right.svg) no-repeat;
  display:block;
  position: left top;
  &.open {
    background-image: url(../images/arrow-down.svg) no-repeat;
    display:block;
    position: left top;
  } 
}
```

I've looked at a couple of examples on code pen, but since this is my first time working with sass & pug, I'm having some difficulty to get this to function.

Comment: How are you adding the `.open` class when the user clicks the `span`?

Comment: @Sean Thanks, I've added how I think the data toggle should work for the accordion but I haven't met with any success.

Comment: That won't add a class on click without javascript. What javascript are you using?

Comment: @Sean The project uses jQuery which I'm not too familiar with.

Comment: You can't toggle a class with just HTML and CSS. You'll have to write custom javascript to toggle that `.open` class. jQuery won't do that out of the box either.